# How add observablecollection to another observablecollection c#

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have ObservableCollection

```
ICollection<Clip> Clipcol = new ICollection<Clip>;
ObservableCollection<Clip> coll = new ObservableCollection<Clip>(Clipcol);
```

And I have class, where I can do something like this

```
public class ClipStorageCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Clip>
            {
                public ClipStorageCollection(Clip collect)
                    : base()
                {
                    this.Add(collect);
                }
            }
```

But I want add to ClipStorageCollection all ObservableCollection coll with all contained clips.
How can I do this?

Comment: How is this adding `ObservableCollection` to `ObservableCollection`? this is instantiating an `ObservableCollection` with `ICollection` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the constructor of `ObservableCollection` that takes an `IEnumerable`.

```
public class ClipStorageCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Clip>
{
    public ClipStorageCollection(IEnumerable<Clip> clips)
        : base(clips)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate it like this:

```
ICollection<Clip> Clipcol = new ICollection<Clip>;
ObservableCollection<Clip> coll = new ObservableCollection<Clip>(Clipcol);
ClipStorageCollection clipStorageCollection = new ClipStorageCollection(coll);
```

If you dont want to pass an `IEnumerable<Clip>` as constructor parameter, you could use the `AddRange` extension method (and add a default constructor):

```
ICollection<Clip> Clipcol = new ICollection<Clip>;
ObservableCollection<Clip> coll = new ObservableCollection<Clip>(Clipcol);
ClipStorageCollection clipStorageCollection = new ClipStorageCollection();
clipStorageCollection.AddRange(coll);
```

Comment: Thnx you! It helps me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question right, but my initial thought is to instantiate ClipStorageCollection, then directly set it to coll, like this

```
ClipStorageCollection myClipStorageCollection= coll;
```

Comment: Before I try go by same way, but i get error 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Client.Classes.Clip>' to 'Client.UI.Dialogs.ViewModel.ClipStorageCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but is it possible for you to use an iterative method:

```
foreach (Clip collect in coll)
{                    
    myClipStorageCollection.add(collect);
}
```